# std::string generates linker error -- const char* does not. why?

Tags: c++, string, std

just like the headline says.. i got this piece of code

```
std::string dir;
(ls == 1) ? dir = "Long" : dir = "Short";
```

which generates error i don´t understand

```
LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _CrtDbgReportW referenced in function 
"void * __cdecl std::_Allocate(unsigned __int64,unsigned __int64,bool)
```

when i switch to

```
const char* dir;
(ls == 1) ? dir = "Long" : dir = "Short";
```

all works pretty fine.

what is the deal there?

Comment: What a bout simply writing `std::string dir = (ls == 1) ? "Long" : "Short"; `?

Comment: Looks like you might have mixed some debug libraries with a release build.

Comment: i am not asking how to make the code work, it does work. i am asking why std::string generates the error and const char* doesn´t. even if i write it on one line it doesn´t compile

Comment: Because you didn't provide the command line for compilation and for linking and the error is there.

Comment: @Nirvikalpa Samadhi: This question is actually very easy to answer: it happens because `std::string` uses `CrtDbgReportW` function internally and `const char*` doesn't.

Comment: The query operator (`?:`) isn't an `if` construct, it is an expression. It's not intended to put side effect statements in the alternate branches.

Answer (score 4):

In

```
std::string dir;
(ls == 1) ? dir = "Long" : dir = "Short";
```

`dir` is a `std::string`, a fairly complex class that will be pulling in bits and pieces from all over the standard library, including memory allocation which appears to be calling a Windows debug helper function, `_CrtDbgReportW`,  under some circumstances. For whatever reason, this debug helper function is not being linked.

But in

```
const char* dir;
(ls == 1) ? dir = "Long" : dir = "Short";
```

`dir` is just a simple pointer, an address. `dir = "Long"` simply points `dir` at the string literal `"long"`. This is just a simple assignment that requires no help from any libraries.